# Variable `FROM` doesnt get expanded in `sed -i 's/$FROM/$TO/g'`

Tags: bash, replace, sed

Someone with better experience then me regarding bashscript that could take a look at this code and explain why no string replacements is taking place. If I run the same command *(text input instead of variables)* in the terminal, then it works.

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "important to escape every \"/\" character"

read -p "Specify the old string you want to replace? (from) " FROM
read -p "Specify the new string you want to use instead? (to) " TO

cp ../backup/mysql/dump.sql ../backup/mysql/dump.sql.backup.$(date +"%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M-%S") \
  && sed -i 's/$FROM/$TO/g' ../backup/mysql/dump.sql
```

Comment: Use double quotes for variables expansion i.e. `sed -i "s/$FROM/$TO/g"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use double quotes for variables expansion instead of single quotes: `"s/$FROM/$TO/g"`

Answer (score 1):

You can even have the `cp` implicitly within the `sed` command itself using `-i(inplace)` option.

```
sed -i.backup.$(date +"%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M-%S") "s/$FROM/$TO/g" ../backup/mysql/dump.sql
```

This will create the backup file as well.